# how to update a column( in SQL) by adding a specific amount to the old one?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, ms-access, sql-update

thats the code...

```
SQL = string.Format("Insert into Orders (AID,ODate) Values({0},'{1}')", AID, odate);
Dbase.ChangeTable(SQL, "Database1.mdb");
SQL = "Select MAX(OID) as MAXOID from Orders";
dt = Dbase.SelectFromTable(SQL, "Database1.mdb");
OID = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
string PID = Session["PID"].ToString();
SQL = string.Format("Insert into ListedProducts (OID,PID,PCat,cnt) Values({0},{1},'{2}',{3})", OID, PID, "B", cnt);
Dbase.ChangeTable(SQL, "Database1.mdb");
Label6.Text = "Your Product has been added to your basket , go to <a href=\"MyBasket.aspx\">your basket </a> to commit your order.";

// HEREEEEEEE///

SQL = String.Format("Update [Orders]  SET [price]=[price]+{0}  Where [OID]={1}", int.Parse(cnt) * pr, OID);
//SQL = "UPDATE [Orders] SET [price]=" + int.Parse(cnt) * pr + " WHERE OID=" + OID;

////////////////
Dbase.ChangeTable(SQL, "Database1.mdb");
```

so it should work and it doesnt show me an error but it doesnt add anything to the database but if i wont be adding it would update.

my database consists of OID,ODate,price,AID..

Comment: Display the insert string before you try to add. Then try the insert string manually.

Comment: What happens if you replace the INSERT statement with a SELECT that uses the same WHERE clause? Do you get a result back? This will check that your WHERE clause and parameters are working.

Comment: ive put a break point and it shows me that the statment is good with the parmeters and stuff..

Comment: Have you confirmed that your application has UPDATE privileges on your database?

Answer (score 0):

Run the SQL Commands manually and ensure your logic is correct... it's possible that your UPDATE is running but not doing anything since your WHERE isn't finding the OID you're passing in.